# How to apply range of values to a partial attribute selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to apply a numeric range on ends with (`id$=`) with jQuery but I couldn't. I tried:

```
[id$="[1-8]"]
```

My code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  $('[id^="text"][id$="[1-8]"]').css("color", "red");
});

</script>

<p id="text1">
  Column 1
</p>

<p id="text2">
  Column 2
</p>
```

Is there any way to get the range using just two numbers (`1-8` for example) with `jQuery` only?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a selector that does pattern matching like this.

Comment: Use the starts with selector and then use `.filter()` to test the last character of the ID.

Comment: It wouldn't be much more code to just list some CSS selectors with those IDs: `#text1, #text2, #text3 { color: red; }`

Comment: Apparently you can modify the HTML. Why not give those elements a common class?

Comment: Cases like this are exactly why `class` attributes exist.